# Get-AzSnapshot issues on powershell and cloudshell

Tags: azure, powershell, az, azure-vm

`Get-AzSnapshot` is showing some weird behaviour.

```
Get-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshotName
```

First Issue: The command above gives an error :

```
Resource group 'xxx' could not be found. ErrorCode: ResourceGroupNotFound ErrorMessage: Resource group
     | 'xxx' could not be found. ErrorTarget:  StatusCode: 404 ReasonPhrase: Not Found
```

but there is a command to list the resourcegroup after and before this command and it executes correctly.

Apparently the issue is it cannot find the snapshot but instead it is blaming RG.

Second Issue. Snapshot listed on portal is not listed when just `Get-AzSnapshot` is executed. This is not the issue with being in correct subscription because other command like `az group list` list from all subscriptions. More over the subscription was forcefully loaded with `az account set --subscription c56e18b5–xxx`

Answer (score 0):

### First Issue

I can only reproduce your error using `Get-AzSnapshot` when the resource group is invalid or not found, which will return `ErrorCode: ResourceGroupNotFound`. If you supplied a correct resource group, but an invalid snapshot name, you will instead get `ErrorCode: ResourceNotFound`. I would double check the resource group you are trying to access definitely exists.

If you want to make sure you don't run `Get-AzSnapshot` if the resource group doesn't exist, I would add a error variable with `-ErrorVariable` to store the error result if an exception occured from [`Get-AzResourceGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresourcegroup?view=azps-3.8.0). The error result is stored as type [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netcore-3.1), so we can simply check if the errors found is greater than zero. You can run `$resourceGroupError.GetType().FullName` to get the full type name. We can also use `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to suppress the error from `Get-AzResourceGroup` if the resource group is not found.

```
$resourceGroupName = "demo-RG"
$snapshotName = "demo-snapshot"

# First get resource group
Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -ErrorVariable resourceGroupError -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if ($resourceGroupError.Count -gt 0)
{
    # ResourceGroup doesn't exist
    # Don't get snapshot
    Write-Host "Cannot find $resourceGroupName resource group"
}
else
{
    # ResourceGroup exist
    # Can get snapshot
    Get-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -SnapshotName $snapshotName
}
```

### Second Issue

Only resource groups under your *current active subscription* will be listed if you run `az group list` or `Get-AzResourceGroup`. So if your snapshot is in a specific subscription, and you are not currently set to that subscription, you need to switch to that specific subscription with `az account set --subscription`. For Azure PowerShell, I suggest switching contexts to your active subscription using this [method](http:////learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/manage-subscriptions-azureps?view=azps-3.8.0#change-the-active-subscription).